# Laravel can't Delete data, it can enter on destroy() function but it parameter return null

Tags: php, laravel, crud, laravel-9

So i'm try to delete data on laravel using resource route. but the data remain and still return the function. Im also try to delete the Greens from destroy() parameter, it make $greens containing 'id'. but still, i want to keep destroy() parameter to be (Greens $greens), not just ($greens)

Controller :

```
    public function destroy(Greens $greens)
    {
        //dd($greens->id);
        Greens::destroy($greens->id);
        return redirect('/greens');
    }
```

Form :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


    <table>
        @foreach ($data as $d)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{$d['brand']}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="/greens/{{$d['id']}}" method="POST">
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @csrf
                    <button>Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Greens extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

Route:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\GreensController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('/greens', GreensController::class);
```

i try to var_dump $greens->id but the result is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Laravel Route Resource, there's a format you should follow, refer to this link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

I can see here in your `destroy` function `$greens` is in plural, you should use the singlular form `$green`:

```
public function destroy(Greens $green)
{
    Greens::destroy($green->id);
    return redirect('/greens');
}
```

Comment: its work, thanks for your help, its work when i change $greens to $green

Comment: Not sure what difference changing the name of a variable would make.

Comment: @NigelRen implicit route model binding

Comment: @NigelRen This is how route model binding works, When you write `Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UserController@show')`, your controller parameter name should use the same name as one defined in the route `public function destroy(User $user)`. You can refer here in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-binding

Answer (score 0):

**You can simple do the following:**

1. Your model name needs to be singular so **Green**
2. For the resource it should be `Route::resource('greens', GreensController::class);`

---

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   Green::find($id)->delete();
   return redirect('/greens');
}
```

**In the form:**

```
<form action="/greens/{{ $d->id }}" method="POST">
   @method('DELETE')
   @csrf
   <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: it still did't delete the data and still returning the view

Comment: @WahyuNabillaFarhan check again my modified answer, i think the issue is with your submit button

Comment: Put this code inside  try and catch block and than check. Like:
```public function destroy(Greens $greens)
    {
       try{
        //dd($greens->id);
        Greens::destroy($greens->id);
        return redirect('/greens');
       } catch(\Exception $e){
            echo '<pre>';print_r($e->getMessage());die;
       }
    }```